# Integral of $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos (\pi t) dt$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to determine whether the integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty cos \,(\pi t) \;dt$$

is convergent or divergent.  I rewrote this improper integral as

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to{-\infty}}\int_{x}^0 cos \,(\pi t) \;dt +  \lim \limits_{x \to{\infty}}\int_0^x cos \,(\pi t) \;dt$$

I integrated
$ \lim \limits_{x \to{-\infty}}\int_{x}^0 cos \,(\pi t) \;dt$ 
to get 
$ \frac{sin \,(\pi t)}{2}$
which gives me 
$ \frac{sin \,0}{0} - \frac{sin \,t}{t}$

Obviously I can't divide by 0 so does this mean that the function is divergent, or is there some other step I can take that I'm missing?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \int_x^0 \cos(\pi t)\,\text{d}t = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(0)}{\pi} - \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\right)$$
Note that $t$ doesn't end up in the denominator, nor is there a divide by zero error here.

Comment: Often people will regularize integrals such as these, probably giving this one the value $0$.

Comment: In the context of distributions $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x)\,dx=2\pi \delta(k)$.  So, in distribution, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(\pi x)\,dx=0$$

Comment: @MarkViola thanks for the insight! Can you point to any reference as I'd like to read more about it please?

Comment: @pipo17171 Any rigorous treatise on Fourier Transforms should suffice.

Comment: @MarkViola can you please be more precise? I looked and it's hard to find something that addresses this specific question.

Comment: @pipo17171 Please deepen your search.  You know that as a distribution we have $\mathscr{F}\{1\}(k)=2\pi \delta(k)$, right?

Comment: @MarkViola not useful. thanks for making me give up

Comment: @pipo17171 Do you understand what a distribution is?  Are you familiar with the FT as a distribution?  Heuristically, do you understand the abusive notation $\delta (x)=0$ for $x\ne0$?  With such abusive notation do you see that $\delta(\pi)=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$\int_0^x \cos(\pi t)\,dt=\left[\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\right]_0^x=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\ ;$$
this continues to oscillate between $1/\pi$ and $-1/\pi$ and therefore has no limit as $x\to\infty$.  Hence
$$\int_0^\infty \cos(\pi t)\,dt$$
diverges, and so does
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(\pi t)\,dt\ .$$

Comment: In the context of distributions $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x)\,dx=2\pi \delta(k)$.  So, in distribution, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(\pi x)\,dx=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You've definitely done something wrong with that integration and substitution, if you're getting (a) a $t$ in your final answer (hint: it disappears when you integrate over it) and (b) getting things divided by 0 and/or $t$.

$\int_0^x \cos (\pi t) dt = \sin (\pi x) / \pi$, which takes values from $-1/\pi$ to $1/\pi$ as $x$ varies. If we take the two-sided integral, then we have $\int_{-x}^x \cos (\pi t) dt = (\sin (\pi x) - \sin (-\pi x)) / \pi = 2\sin (\pi x) / \pi$, because the function we are integrating is even (and hence has the same area to the left and right of the y-axis). This also behaves sinusoidally as $x$ varies, so even if we just try to take the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ we can see we're not going to get a nice limit.

Comment: In the context of distributions $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(k x)\,dx=2\pi \delta(k)$.  So, in distribution, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(\pi x)\,dx=0$$