# Does the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sin x$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Although I am not sure, but I think the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sin x \:dx$ is divergent. I have done a proof for that, which looks like-

> Firstly I take $\int_{0}^{n \pi}\sin x\:dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin
>  x\:dx+\int_{\pi}^{2 \pi}\sin x\:dx+...+\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n \pi}\sin
>  x\:dx$
>  Then after a little calculation, I get $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin
>  x\:dx=2,\: \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi}\sin x\:dx=-2,\: ...,\:
>  \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n \pi}\sin x\:dx=(-1)^{n-1}2$
>  Therefore,
>    $\int_{0}^{n \pi}\sin x\:dx=\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r-1}2$
>  Now,
>    $\int_0^\infty \sin x \:dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n \pi}\sin
>  x\:dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r-1}2$, but this limit does
>    not exist because the alternating series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty
>  (-1)^{r-1}2$ is divergent.

Am I right? Can anybody tell me is there any mistake in my proof?If there is any, please mark it help me with a proper way out.
Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: You are right, but it goes easier, You can simply directy integrate $\int_0^{n\pi}\sin(x)dx$, without sums. It is $\int_0^{n\pi}\sin(x)dx=[-\cos(x)]_0^{n\pi}=1-(-1)^{n}$.

Comment: How could $1-\cos x$ converge ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829923/integral-of-int-infty-infty-cos-pi-t-dt?rq=1

Comment: It doesn't converge, because it doesn't satisfiy the definition of improper integral.